# Create Method on User Model (bcrypt)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

After looking at the new laravel version 5.4 i notice when using "`$user = User::create(request(['name', 'email','password']));`" the password isnt automatically bcrypt the password, is it me, or isnt the password hashed by default on the model create method? I dont remember, but isnt supposed the method "create" already do this?

Comment: No it might be your code. Laravel code for creating user in AuthController using bcryt() for securing password

Comment: By default the password is bcrypted in RegisterController! where did you get that line of code???

Answer (score 3):

In User Model you need to add below function, for default password encrypted.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
        {
            if($value != ""){
                $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/hashing#introduction)

> If you are using the built-in LoginController and RegisterController classes that are included with your Laravel application, they will automatically use Bcrypt for registration and authentication.

If you use `RegisterController.php` that is shipped in Laravel you don't need to `Hash` password manually else you need to use

```
 return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']), //<==encrypt here
        ]);
```

Check the register Controller here:

> https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L63

Comment: hello , in my case im creating a custom registrationController

Comment: If you `extend` this https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php 

you don't need else you need to manually encrypt

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following.

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

use App\User;

class RegistrationsController extends Controller
{

```
public function store()
{
    //validate the form
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'name'=> ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'=> ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password'=>['required', 'string', 'min:4', 'confirmed'],
    ]);

    //create and save the user

        $user =User::create([
       'name'=>request('name'), 
       'email'=>request('email'),

        //hash your password 

       'password'=>Hash::make(request('password'))
       ]);

    //sign in the user
    auth()->login($user);

    //redirect to the homepage
     return redirect()->home();
}
```

}